# reference project from another solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

I'm new in c#
my question is how could I reference between 2 project in different solutions  ?

I tried add project reference but it's just work for project that is in the same solution and I didn't find any helpful resources on the internet

Comment: Ideally, compile it into a DLL or Nuget package and add it as a reference in your other project. Your other option would be to just add the project to both solutions, but I would not recommend doing that because that creates some weird dependencies where there probably doesn't need to be any.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot reference projects from different solutions. What you can do is add the existing library project to the solution you want to reference it in. In the Solution Explorer, right-click the solution and select *Add -> Existing Project*. You can then navigate to the project file of the project you want to reference and it will be added to the solution. The project will not be copied or modified at all. The path of the project is simply added to the solution file, which you can view in a text editor to see for yourself if you like. It's then treated like any other project in that solution, including for the purposes of referencing.